# Maven + Kotlin/Java - programmatically get jar file from local maven repo

Tags: java, kotlin, maven, jvm

I want to read any jar file located in the maven local repo during the tests runtime.
For example, the following code will work and will read jar file:

```
File("/Users/myusername/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar")
```

When I get value from "java.class.path" property, I can see that path to jar file is in the list of classpath:

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path")
```

Output:

```
...:/Users/myusername/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-classes-epoll/4.1.87.Final/netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.87.Final.jar:/Users/myusername/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

But I cannot understand how to get the same file without specifying full path to the jar file. My goal is to write code that will run on any machine with maven.

I tried to use just filename:

```
File("log4j-1.2.17.jar")
```

But it gets nothing, because by default it looks into application classpath directory.

**Additional context**

I use TestContainers to build and run containers for integration tests. I want to build and run GenericContainer using basic image with Java and executable jar from our company private repository. I have this jar in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>private.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>private.artifact.id</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <classifier>exec</classifier>
        <version>${jar.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is a code sample to build and run Container:

```
GenericContainer<Nothing>(
ImageFromDockerfile()
    .withFileFromFile(jarName, File("/Users/username/.m2/repository/groupId/artifactId/version/$jarName"))
    .withDockerfileFromBuilder { builder: DockerfileBuilder ->
        builder
            .from("urlToBaseImageWithJava")
            .copy(jarName,"/app/$jarName")
            .entryPoint("java", "-jar", "/app/$jarName")
            .build()
    }
```

).apply {
withNetwork(myNetwork)
start()
}

Comment: *My goal is to write code that will run on any machine with maven.* That's very unclear

Comment: `I want to read any jar file located in the maven local repo during the tests runtime` what is the purpose of that? You can run your unit tests without accessing the jar files? Please elaborate more what exactly you are trying to achieve? By defining a dependency in the pom file you have the jar's on the classpath... etc.?

Comment: @g00se path to maven local repo may vary from machine to machine. Also in some cases it can be set via maven parameter -Dmaven.repo.local.

Comment: @khmarbaise I decided not to provide this context because I don't think it's really important for this particular question. But okay: I use TestContainers framework for testing. And I want to build and run GenericContainer using basic image with Java and any Jar file from the local repo. In fact I have jar file that I want to place into test container in my pom.xml.

Comment: I have updated my question and provided you more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If under "run containers for integration tests" you actually mean running `mvn verify`, then maven way is to copy required dependencies to known location using `maven-dependency-plugin` and pass the location(s) to `maven-failsafe-plugin` via `systemProperties`, for example:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <!-- 
                should be pre-integration-test, actually, however
                in that case we will depend on plugin execution order
            -->
            <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>private.group.id</groupId>
                        <artifactId>private.artifact.id</artifactId>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        <version>${jar.version}</version>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <destFileName>my-cool-jar.jar</destFileName>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <systemProperties>
            <myCoolJarLocation>${project.build.directory}/my-cool-jar.jar</myCoolJarLocation>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After that you may discover location of your jar using `myCoolJarLocation` system property.

Comment: Brilliant! Andrey, your solution is great! Thanks a lot!

By the way, I do not even need to use maven-failsafe-plugin and specify destination file name, copying artifacts to ${basedir}/target is enough for me, because I already have jar versions (and know names) in my code - they are passed by maven-resource-plugin with filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Maven Dependency Resolver library to programmatically resolve the JAR file's path based on its coordinates like group id, artifact id, etc.

Try with this. It uses the Maven Dependency Resolver library. Its extense but effective. It assumes also you have Maven Dependency Resolver dependences in your proyect and Aether libraries in your classpath:

```
    import org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.tree.DependencyTreeBuilder;
    import org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.tree.DependencyTreeBuilderException;
    import org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.tree.DependencyTreeBuilderSession;
    import org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.tree.DefaultDependencyTreeBuilder;
    import org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.tree.DependencyNode;
    import org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.tree.DependencyNodeVisitor;
    import org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem;
    import org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystemSession;
    import org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystemSession;
    import org.eclipse.aether.artifact.Artifact;
    import org.eclipse.aether.artifact.DefaultArtifact;
    import org.eclipse.aether.collection.CollectRequest;
    import org.eclipse.aether.graph.Dependency;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class MavenLocalRepositoryReader {
    
        public static File getJarFileFromMavenLocalRepo(String groupId, String artifactId, String version) {
            RepositorySystem repoSystem = new DefaultRepositorySystem();
            RepositorySystemSession repoSession = MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newSession();
            Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact(groupId, artifactId, "jar", version);
    
            CollectRequest collectRequest = new CollectRequest();
            collectRequest.setRoot(new Dependency(artifact, ""));
    
            DependencyTreeBuilder treeBuilder = new DefaultDependencyTreeBuilder();
    
            try {
                DependencyNode rootNode = treeBuilder.buildDependencyTree(repoSystem, repoSession, null, collectRequest);
    
                List<File> jarFiles = new ArrayList<>();
                DependencyNodeVisitor visitor = new DependencyNodeVisitor() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean visit(DependencyNode node) {
                        Artifact nodeArtifact = node.getArtifact();
                        if (nodeArtifact != null && "jar".equals(nodeArtifact.getExtension())) {
                            jarFiles.add(nodeArtifact.getFile());
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public boolean endVisit(DependencyNode node) {
                        return true;
                    }
                };
    
                rootNode.accept(visitor);
    
                if (!jarFiles.isEmpty()) {
                    return jarFiles.get(0); // Assuming there is only one JAR file for the given coordinates
                }
    
            } catch (DependencyTreeBuilderException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
            return null;
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Example usage
            String groupId = "log4j";
            String artifactId = "log4j";
            String version = "1.2.17";
    
            File jarFile = getJarFileFromMavenLocalRepo(groupId, artifactId, version);
    
            if (jarFile != null) {
                System.out.println("Found JAR file: " + jarFile.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                System.out.println("JAR file not found in the Maven local repository.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I cannot figure out what is dependency group/name for first 6 imports. Would you be so kind to copy their names? I added org.apache.maven:maven-resolver-provider, but it helped me to resolve only eclipse imports :(

Comment: Can you check if its the maven.shared... too and it's the last version? If that's true it might not give you problems. Confirm and lets see if we can do something else.

Comment: Ah, I tried many maven.shared libs, no luck. Is it possible to check what libs do you have for this code?

Comment: I see. Looks like your solution is for maven 2. Some of classes are deprecated and do not work with maven3. So I have to work on this. Anyway thanks a lot!